# EF5 DB First table names are pluralized when generating SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.5

I have used the EF db first approach to develop my data layer. I have a table called Activity in the DB and used the repository pattern for data access. There is a method called GetAll() which returns all the activities.

My issue is when entity framework is generating the sql to access the data the table name is pluralized.

eg.

Its generating:

```
select * from dbo.Activities
```

instead of:

```
select * from dbo.Activity
```

Couldn't figure out why its doing this. Anyone have an idea why?

[image]

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Maybe because you left the "Allow Pluralization" checkbox checked on the final step of a model importing wizard.

Comment: I generated again without ticking.... its still doing it

Comment: To be exact the checkbox caption is "Pluralize or singularize generated object names". It's is checked by default and you should uncheck it. I have just tested it and it works.

Comment: Nope its still the same... doing more investigation :(

Comment: Can you show the entity model and dbset property generated by EF?

Comment: As you said you are using DB first approach, I am confused why its using plural names while querying . I checked couple of posts on the web and seems like following code might be worth trying. Have you tried this?

`protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelbuilder)
    {
        modelbuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }`

Comment: I think this method is used when u r using code first approach... when I ran it it said the model is changed run the code first approach... anyway trying more..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with my project. Completely re-did the data layer project separately again and it seems fine now.